# Analytic and bounded implies uniform continuity

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be analytic and bounded in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid Re(z)>0\}$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid Re(z)>C\}=:D$ for every $C>0.$

For uniform continuity, I have to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in D$ with $\|x-y\|<\delta$ we have $\|f(x)-f(y)\|<\varepsilon$. How can I find such a $\delta$? I don't know how to use the assumptions that $f$ is analytic (i.e. can be written as a power series) and bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose $|f|\le M$ in the right half plane. Cauchy's estimates give $|f'(x+iy)|\le M/x$ everywhere in the right half plane.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I use the derivative to show uniform continuity?

Comment: @mathstackuser  What would you do if you had a function on the real line whose derivative was $\le 1$ in absolute value everywhere?

Comment: @zhw. I am also thinking about this problem. I know that in the real setting, bounded derivative implies uniform continuity. But is the proof of this the same in the complex setting?